# Is it possible to add a child page from a form in the frontend in Wagtail CMS?

Tags: django, wagtail

Is it possible to add a child page from a form in the frontend in Wagtail CMS?

The reason for this is that when I use the formbuilder the content added is in the Forms section, but I want the content from the form to be a page on its own as this is primary content in the application I built.

I was thinking this is possible with the API, but I would think there would be a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Please heed the note at the top of https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/contrib/forms/index.html I doubt form builder is the right tool for this.

Adding a page "from the front end" implies to me that you want unauthenticated users to add pages to your site and you are not going to provide a way for them to edit those pages. If that is not the requirement, I would suggest you instead create users and allow them very limited access to the Wagtail admin. OR you could use Django restframework to create an API endpoint do CRUD for these pages.

If you add some details about what you are trying to do and why, you might get better advice.